# how to handle unicode data in delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

in my application ,i am sending data from my application to database 
i am getting some odd characters in my database like this

[image]

i am sending my data like this

```
var
 w:widestring;
 u:utf8string;
begin
   w:=data //data is function to get some info(string)
   u:=utf8encode(w);
   sendfn(u);
end;
```

i am using utf8_decode(my get data) in my php code before adding to  my database.

and my database and tables collation is utf8_general_ci

can anyone help me in this issue

Comment: What does sendfn() actually look like?  Does it take a UTF8String as input, or does it an AnsiString or UnicodeString instead?

Comment: How do you connect to MySql? BDE, ADO , dbExpress or other?

Comment: sendfunction take value as utf8 string simply sendfn(x;y;u:utf8string); where xand y or other  data i sent ,actually i sent data to my webpage www.mysite.com/index.php?action=add ,hope i am clear ,if i missed some thing please let me know 
regards

Comment: What does "weird data" mean? Question mark. Square box. What?  Oh. I see. The picture looks like your unicode font does not include all the glyphs. Try changing your font on the control to Arial Unicode

Answer (score 0):

It's an educated guess, but does the Data function return an UTF-8 string instead of a WideString? I think the error could be in this Data function that you're calling, which returns the data in the wrong string format.

Comment: function doesnt return any string ,it is used write data .see 3rd comment in first post

Answer (score 0):

The php function `utf8_decode` converts characters from `utf-8` to `ISO-8859-1`. If the path your data take (the browser or whatever component you use to send your data to the web server (http request, your php installation, your webpage and your database connection) from your delphi app to your database that is behind you webpage are able to support and configured to use `utf-8` data you don't need the `utf8_decode` function, you can just insert your data the way it comes.

If you haven't already configured php to work with `UTF-8`, be aware that it is difficult and never works 100% (for me at least it never did), so maybe it would be better for you to use data in your locale encoding.